# Only ONE button can be clicked per row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I'm trying to code that only ONE button can be selected per ROW.** I tried too many this and this is the closest I did it.

I can selected and deselect it. But only one per row can be selected.
What my code does:

I can select any button and it will be added a class to it get red.
so now this button is selected. I can unselect it as well.

This is my code:

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {
            $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
        }else {
            $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
        }
    });

<style>
   .selected {
       color:red;
   }
</style>
```

Some print to help:
[image]

Comment: Ok..but what do you want?

Comment: implement some code that only one button can be clicked per row... on this way that i've done doesn't work.

Comment: so what does your code do? it would be really helpful if you can share a fiddle with us, with the issue reproduced.

Comment: i edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like following. Just find the others `.btn` and remove `.selected` from them and set `data-selected` to `false` when you are selecting a `.btn`. Hope this will help you.

```js
$('.btn').click(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('data-selected') === 'true') {
        $(this).attr('data-selected', 'false');
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.btn').not(this)
               .removeClass('selected').attr('data-selected', 'false');
        $(this).attr('data-selected', 'true');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
});
```

```css
.selected {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="1.22" class="btn"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="1.33" class="btn" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="1.44" class="btn" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="1.22" class="btn" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="1.33" class="btn" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="1.44" class="btn" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You can chain jQuery calls like this: `$(this).attr('data-selected', 'false').removeClass('selected');`. It will make code more readable imho.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make radio buttons that looks like buttons, if you give them the same name they will already have the functionality you are looking for built in.

http://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/YB8UW/616/

```
    <ul class="donate-now">
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="a25" name="amount" />
    <label for="a25">$25</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="a50" name="amount" />
    <label for="a50">$50</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="a75" name="amount" checked="checked" />
    <label for="a75">$75</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="a100" name="amount" />
    <label for="a100">$100</label>
</li>

</ul>
<br>
<ul class="donate-now">
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="b25" name="amountb" />
    <label for="b25">$25</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="b50" name="amountb" />
    <label for="b50">$50</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="b75" name="amountb" checked="checked" />
    <label for="b75">$75</label>
</li>
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="b100" name="amountb" />
    <label for="b100">$100</label>
</li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a working example for you which can be used for multiple rows: https://jsfiddle.net/448feo3j/

```
$('.button-default').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.button-default').removeClass('button-clicked').attr('data-selected', false);
    $(this).addClass('button-clicked').attr('data-selected', true);
});
```